# Php page containing database results not loading completely sometimes

Tags: php, apache

I have this webpage [Online Reggae Vinyl Shop](http://www.jahkenkenrecords.com) and when browsing the artists, labels or releases page, sometimes it freezes and is not completely displayed.  Usually this happens when I request 100 results per page.

I use an echo line by line in PHP to show the SQL data in an html  container. Is it better to put all code in a variable and then echo it?

There are no errors in the error log. I would think that 100 results are not so much for time out errors or something similar. Could it have anything to do with my server configuration (Apache/Php)?

Comment: The query is not the issue. Its a simple join query for 100 records, around 5 to 7 fields for each  row. The problem is that randomly the pages dont show full , if you refresh normally its fixed but i dont understand why.

Comment: Try ruling out the javascript.  Test the page without js scripts.

Comment: Which database and database client are you using?

Comment: I am using Maria DB and access through mysqli from PHP. I dont use javascript on page loading.

Comment: Which error logs have you looked at?